# Sort ArrayList w.r.t Date in java

Tags: java

I am trying to sort ArrayList w.r.t termDate 
ArrayList contains firstName,lastName,email,startDate,termDate

Dates can be either empty or null.
I have to compare accordingly and put all the null/empty date values at the end.

```
Collections.sort(usersList, new Comparator<User>() {
                public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
                    if(o1.getTermDate() == null && o2.getTermDate() == null)
                        return 0; //They are both null, both equal
                    if(o1.getTermDate() == null && o2.getTermDate() != null)
                        return -1; // The first is null and the second is not, return the first as lower than the second
                    if(o1.getTermDate() != null && o2.getTermDate() == null)
                        return 1; //The first is not null and the second is, return the first as higher than the second
                    else
                        return o1.getTermDate().compare(o2.getTermDate()); //Return the actual comparison
                }
            });
```

It is not compiling compare method.

Please guide.

Comment: You need to call [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo-java.util.Date-) method and not `compare`.

Comment: @Tunaki
thanks.
compareTo is not giving compilation issues.
do i need to pass the Collections.sort(..) to ArrayList again or the existing userList will be sorted and I can access it?

Comment: `Collections.sort` sorts the list in-place. That means the list given as argument will be sorted after the call to this method.

Comment: @Tunaki
I don't understand why it is not swapping in my case.
i have put sysouts to check
Term Date: null 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0
Term Date2: -1 null 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0
Term Date: 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 2015-12-31 00:00:00.0
Term Date4: 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 2015-12-31 00:00:00.0
Term Date: 2015-12-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date3: 1 2015-12-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date: 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date3: 1 2015-08-31 00:00:00.0 null
Term Date: null null
Term Date1: 0 null null

Answer (score 1):

You should change `return o1.getTermDate().compare(o2.getTermDate());` to `return o1.getTermDate().compareTo(o2.getTermDate());` Because the class `java.util.Date;` has not method called `compare`.